# Retrieve old IP for VM

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, static-ip-address

I'm with google cloud platform, and recently my VM IP changed after a stop-start. Unfortunately I didn't have a Static IP. How do I retrieve my old IP back? This is very important as I have a lot of printed material with that. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If you had an `Ephemeral Internal IP` assigned to the VM and you released it, you can set it back either through a `Custom Ephemeral` IP address(this will as well be released next time), or a `Reserved Static Internal IP` where you have to select *Let me choose* instead of *automatic*:

[image]

If you have released the `Public/External` IP address, I hate to give you the bad news, but you will have redo the paperwork, because now the IP may belong to a different project and there is no way to recover it.

**Ephemeral external IP addresses:**

*An ephemeral external IP address is an IP address that doesn't persist beyond the life of the resource. When you create an instance or forwarding rule without specifying an IP address, the resource is automatically assigned an ephemeral external IP address.*

*Ephemeral external IP addresses are released from a resource if you delete the resource. For VM instances, the ephemeral external IP address is also released if you stop the instance. After you restart the instance, it is assigned a new ephemeral external IP address. If you have an existing VM that doesn't have an external IP address, you can assign one to it. Forwarding rules always have an IP address, whether external or internal, so you don't need to assign an IP address to a forwarding rule after it is created.*